# How to detect intersection of a UIBezierPath and erase it

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibezierpath

I am making an `iOS` drawing app and would like to add functionality where erasing a `UIBezierPath` will erase the whole path and not just overlay the segment with a white color.

I have an array of `UIBezierPaths` stored, but I am not sure how efficient it is to loop through the entire array for each touch point, detect if it intersects with the current touch point, and remove it from the array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to loop through path at least. They are independent after all.

An `UIBezierPaths` has method `contains` which would tell you if a point is inside the path. If that is usable then what you need to do is simply

```
paths = paths.filter { !$0.contains(touchPoint) }
```

But since this is drawing app it is safe to assume you are using stroke and not fill which will most likely not work with `contains` the way you want it to.

You could do the intersection manually and it should have relatively good performance up until you have too many points. But when you have too many points I wager drawing performance will be more of your concern. Still the intersection may be a bit problematic with including some stroke line width; user would need to cross the center of your line to detect a hit.

There is a way though to convert stroked path to filled path. Doing that will then enable you to use `contains` method. The method is called `replacePathWithStrokedPath` but the thing is that it only exists on `CGContext` (At least I have never managed to find an equivalent on `UIBezierPath`). So procedure to do so includes creating a context. For instance something like this will work:

```
static func convertStrokePathToFillPath(_ path: UIBezierPath) throws -> UIBezierPath {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0), true, 1.0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { throw NSError(domain: "convertStrokePathToFillPath", code: 500, userInfo: ["dev_message":"Could not generate image context"]) }

    context.addPath(path.cgPath)
    context.setLineWidth(path.lineWidth)
    // TODO: apply all possible settings from path to context
    context.replacePathWithStrokedPath()

    guard let returnedPath = context.path else { throw NSError(domain: "convertStrokePathToFillPath", code: 500, userInfo: ["dev_message":"Could not get path from context"]) }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return UIBezierPath(cgPath: returnedPath)
}
```

So the result should look something like:

```
static func filterPaths(_ paths: [UIBezierPath], containingPoint point: CGPoint) -> [UIBezierPath] {
    return paths.filter { !(try! convertStrokePathToFillPath($0).contains(point)) }
}
```

Comment: For converting to a stroked path to a filled path without going through a context see `CGPath.copy(strokingWithWidth:...)`. (It's a method on the underlying CGPath rather than the higher-level UIBezierPath.)

Comment: @RobNapier Thank You for that. I have been looking for the thing for years but never found it. I would not think of it to be on `CGPath` at all. From objectiveC where this started the function is `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath`... Imagine my frustrations trying to find it. In the end I simply thought it must be a part of private API.